Desaparición de evento OnClick Android Studio
tengo un problema y no se si a alguien mas le haya pasado y encontrara una solución, resulta que cree una función con la cual trato de que vaya de un formulario a otro, pero al momento de aplicar mi evento OnClic dicha función no me sale en ningún lado

Estos serian los eventos que me muestran, pero pese a tener una funcion con el mismo nombre, por el echo de no ser del mismo formulario no funciona



Dónde estás asociando la función al evento? También muestra el código donde está esa función como texto.

Hola, actualmente estoy llamando las funciones en estos bloques de codigo                                                                                                        <ImageView                     android:id="@+id/imageView"                     android:layout_width="match_parent"                     android:layout_height="match_parent"                     android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"                     android:scaleType="centerCrop"                     android:onClick="navegarNuevosEquipos"                     android:src="@drawable/argentina" />

La función del atributo onClick debe estar en el mismo contexto de la vista, por ejemplo, en la misma actividad. Además debe ser pública y tener un único parámetro de tipo View.
Así debería funcionar:
fun navegarNuevosEquipos(vista: View) {
    val intent = Intent(this, frm_nuevo_equipo::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

También es posible agregar el listener por código.
findViewById<Button>(R.id.boton)
  .setOnClickListener {
      val intent = Intent(this, frm_nuevo_equipo::class.java)
      startActivity(intent)
  }


Muchísimas gracias, pude resolverlo con el primer bloque de código que mandaste
